# 'rails generate thumbs_up' command does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am still new to Ruby on Rails and have used it for a brief time about two years ago. Now, I am using it for my school project and I am running into this problem when I tried to use `thumbs_up` gem.

1. I installed thumbs_up gem. Normally, I run 'bundle install' but I had to run 'gem install thumbs_up"
2. When I ran 'rails g thumbs_up', I got the following error:

> Could not find generator 'thumb_up'. Maybe you meant 'helper', 'jbuilder' or 'job'.

I searched on Google for solution, but I could not find it.

Comment: Did you added the gem in Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I did. I installed thumbs_up 0.6.9. I am using Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.0P0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux].

Answer (score 0):

Gem author here. As I mentioned in the issue, looks like you were spelling the generator incorrectly.

I've just verified that the following steps happen without error on my system (MacOS):

1. `gem install rails`
2. `rails --version` "Rails 5.0.0.1"
3. `rails new foo`
4. Edit Gemfile to add `gem 'thumbs_up'
5. `bundle install`
6. `bundle exec rails g thumbs_up`

If you can give more detailed error logs and steps to reproduce, I'm happy to help.